# How many solutions are there to $2^a + 3^b = 2^c + 3^d$?

Tags: number-theory

Are there only finite quadruples of non-negative integers $(a,b,c,d)$ that satisfy the following equation:

$$2^a + 3^b = 2^c + 3^d \quad ?$$

with $a \neq c$.

I found these:

- $5 = 2^2 + 3^0 = 2^1 + 3^1$
- $11 = 2^3 + 3^1 = 2^1 + 3^2$
- $17 = 2^4 + 3^0 = 2^3 + 3^2$
- $35 = 2^5 + 3^1 = 2^3 + 3^3$
- $259 = 2^8 + 3^1 = 2^4 + 3^5$

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from taking $c=a$ and $d=b$?

Comment: I think you mean that $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$?

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A085634) says there are no more below $10^{4000}$  It seems very likely you have them all.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson: I added the condition $a+b \neq c+d$

Comment: You probably just want to say $a \neq c$.  Your first solution violates $a+b \neq c+d$

Comment: @RossMillikan: yes, you are right

Comment: In all the cases you have shown, the minimum of $b$ and $d$ is $0$ or $1$. I think that might be the general case.

Comment: $$2^a+3^b=2^c+3^d\iff2^a-2^c=3^d-3^b\iff2^c(2^x-1)=3^b(3^y-1)$$ But $\gcd(2^c,3^b)=1$, so, unless $b=c=0$, we have $3^y=2^c+1$, and $2^x=3^b+1$, in which case see [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture).

Comment: @Lucian, I do not think that is right, since some prime factors of $2^{x}-1$ may be present in $3^{y}-1$. The correct conclusion would be $2^{c}||(3^{y}-1)$ and $3^{b}||(2^{x}-1)$.

Comment: @Vor: regarding your flag, seeing that it has been open for more than a week, I can only tell you that the moderators have not been able to decide whether to carry out the migration. This is mostly due to Ross Millikan having point out the relevant OEIS entry. I encourage you to actually post a request to http://meta.mathoverflow.net asking directly whether this question would be considered to be on-topic for migration. If you receive a positive answer there, please flag again and we will be happy to move it over for you.

Comment: @WillieWong: ok, thanks!

Comment: The question is now asked on MathOverflow: [How many solutions to $2^a + 3^b = 2^c + 3^d$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/164624) (I thought it might be useful to mention this here for the people who stumble upon this post.)